# netty eats 100% of CPU

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, epoll

I'm running a server on netty, and found out that some threads initialized by java server application after a while start to eat 100% of CPU. I've tried to initialize boss and worker group with different number of threads but the result is same.

What could be the reason for it?

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); 
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(50);
try {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { 
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast("ReadTimeOutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(20));
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new streamDecoder());
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new streamEncoder());

            ch.pipeline().addLast(new validationHandler());
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new streamDecryptor());
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new streamEncryptor());
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new msgValidatedHandler());
         }
     })
     .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
     .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
```

Comment: What threads are eating 100% CPU? Are they Netty's thread? Also why 50 threads for workergroup?

Comment: I can see that number of threads increases constantly and never reduced.
50 threads for worker group was set up for faster proccessing of numerous concurrent connections. However decreased to 5 works pretty good.

Comment: Have you tried producing thread dumps to see what code is executing?

Comment: I found out that threads consuming most of CPU time are nioEventLoopGroup-3-2,1,4 (see screenshot) and CPU samples show io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select() to be on the top of self time CPU consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for `sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector high cpu` brings up a few hits from as last at 2015. Are you running an older version of Netty?

Also see https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3857 - you may want to try running with `-Dorg.jboss.netty.epollBugWorkaround=true`.

Comment: This what jstack showed on Windows 2012 R2, however under ubuntu 12 it's much alike (if 100% the same) as stated here https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/327

The question is can I setup systemproperty right in the code like this?
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     System.setProperty("org.jboss.netty.epollBugWorkaround", "true");
...

Comment: You should be able to set the property in code, but it probably needs to be done as early as possible, before any Netty classes are loaded. First line in main() is probably easiest.